# Getting all UIElements in a specific Point

Tags: c#, uwp

How can I get all UIElements at a specific point in UWP? I want to get all UIElements when the user release the pointer (in PointerReleased event). 
I have used VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates method but it returns null value.

CS FILE :

```
private void  drawingPanel_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e) 

            PointerPoint endPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(this.drawingPanel);            
            List<UIElement> list = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(endPoint.Position, this) as List<UIElement>;              

        }
```

UI XAML :

```
 <UserControl  ***** bla bla *****>    

        <UserControl.Resources>  


            <DataTemplate x:Key="ImageTemplate">
                <Viewbox Stretch="UniformToFill" StretchDirection="Both"  >
                    <Grid>
                        <ScrollViewer MinZoomFactor="1" MaxZoomFactor="3" ZoomMode="Disabled"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                            <Image Source="{Binding BlockData}"  Height="{Binding ScreenHeight, Mode=TwoWay}"  Width="{Binding ScreenWidth, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                   Holding="Image_Holding" 
                                   PointerPressed="Image_PointerPressed" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </Viewbox>
            </DataTemplate>


            <DataTemplate x:Key="TextTemplate" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">

                <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="Both" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1">
                    <RichEditBox  Width="{Binding ScreenWidth, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="richEditor" l:RtfText.RichText="{Binding BlockData}" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0"  IsHitTestVisible="True" IsTapEnabled="True" GotFocus="richEditor_GotFocus" >
                    </RichEditBox>
                </Viewbox>

            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="GapTemplate">
                <Grid Height="20" >
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>

            <l:NoteTypeTemplateSelector x:Key="NoteTypeTemplateSelector"
            TextTemplate="{StaticResource TextTemplate}"
            ImageTemplate="{StaticResource ImageTemplate}"
            GapTemplate="{StaticResource GapTemplate}">
            </l:NoteTypeTemplateSelector>

        </UserControl.Resources>

        <Grid Name="ContainerGrid" Background="White"  PointerPressed="ContainerGrid_PointerPressed" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ListView  x:Name="NoteList" Background="Transparent" 
                       Grid.Row="1"                     
                       Style="{StaticResource ListViewStyle1}"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"                 
                       ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource NoteTypeTemplateSelector}">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <ContentPresenter/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListView>
            <SwapChainPanel Name="DxPanel"  Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed"></SwapChainPanel>
            <c:DrawingControl x:Name="drawingPanel"  Grid.Row="1" 
                              Holding="drawingPanel_Holding" 
                              PointerPressed="drawingPanel_PointerPressed"
                              PointerMoved="drawingPanel_PointerMoved"
                              PointerReleased="drawingPanel_PointerReleased"
                              PointerWheelChanged="drawingPanel_PointerWheelChanged"
                              PointerExited="drawingPanel_PointerExited"

                              ManipulationStarted="drawingPanel_ManipulationStarted"
                              ManipulationDelta="drawingPanel_ManipulationDelta" 
                              ManipulationCompleted="drawingPanel_ManipulationCompleted"></c:DrawingControl>
            <c:ReadModeToolbar x:Name="ReadModeToolbar" Grid.Row="0"></c:ReadModeToolbar>
            <c:EditModeToolbar x:Name="EditModeToolbar" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Collapsed"></c:EditModeToolbar>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" x:Name="InfoText" Text="Offset"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper.findelementsinhostcoordinates.aspx) will return an enumeration of all of the elements at a specific point.

The PointerReleased event includes the pointer position in its [PointerRoutedEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.pointerroutedeventargs.aspx).[GetCurrentPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.pointerroutedeventargs.getcurrentpoint.aspx)() method.

Pass the same UIElement (likely your Page) to GetCurrentPoint and FindElementsInHostCoordinates so the coordinate systems will match.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I tried this method but method returns null value. I have edit my question you can see codes.

Comment: You need to use the same coordinates. You're getting the point relative to the drawing panel then using that relative to this. Use the same element in both places so the coordinates match.

Comment: I tried that but the result is same, this methos always returns empty.   I have already tried like that : PointerPoint p = e.GetCurrentPoint(this.testGrid);
            
            var list = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(p.RawPosition, this.testGrid) as List<UIElement>;

Comment: OK, Thanks Rob. I found the problem, this method return IEnumarable list and when I tried to cast to List<UIElement> I got null. When I tried to iterate with foreach I got it. Thanks again.